# Reflection: inconsistent framework behavior with GetRuntimeProperty methods

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.5

When playing around with reflection in the new .NET Framework 4.5, I encountered a strange behavior that I found quite unexpected. The namespace System.Reflection provides some new extension methods for exploiting Type objects. Two of those are GetRuntimeProperty(string name) and GetRuntimeProperties().

Now imagine that you have a simple object with an internal property.

```
public class ObjectBase
{
    protected int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you now try to exploit this type.

```
var properties = typeof(ObjectBase).GetRuntimeProperties();
// properties.Count = 2

var idProperty = typeof(ObjectBase).GetRuntimeProperty("Id");
var nameProperty = typeof(ObjectBase).GetRuntimeProperty("Name");
// idProperty = null
// nameProperty = System.String Name
```

As expected the `properties` object holds two property definition for the Id and Name property defintions and the nameProperty holds the Name property definition. What was not expected was the `idProperty` object to be null...

Coming from the .NET Framework, I guess this was intended by Microsoft architects but I must say it does not seem like something you would really expect to happen. I do believe such similar methods should behave the same but it seems that GetRuntimeProperty filters on public properties where GetRuntimeProperties apply no filters.

**Does anybody have a reasonable explanation on why do Microsoft decided that those similar methods should have different behaviors? A design error?**

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that using this is only required in a Store app.  So what you are seeing is a compromise, IInspectable is not exactly a rich interface.

Comment: They completely buggered up the new reflection APIs. It's a mess in so many ways I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

Internally `GetRuntimeProperty` calls `Type.GetProperty(name)` which searches for the **public property** with the specified name. Property `Id` is protected, thus it cannot be found.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetRuntimeProperty(this Type type, string name)
{
    CheckAndThrow(type);
    return type.GetProperty(name);
}
```

On the other hand `GetRuntimeProperties` returns both public and non-public properties

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetRuntimeProperties(this Type type)
{
    CheckAndThrow(type);
    return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public |
                              BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

[Explanation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535795.aspx) `GetRuntimeProperties` purpose is returning `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` collection of all properties, leaving you with filtering that collection via **LINQ**. You can select public, non-public or any other type of properties. With single property returned by `GetRuntimeProperty` you don't need that flexibility, thus it is restricted for most common usage.

Comment: The question is: shy is this designed like this. Doesn't make much sense. Seems like a design error to me.

Comment: As @Steven said, I actually understand that it is coded like this internally but what I don't understand is why those methods behave differently. I updated my question to be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @Ucodia , Steven - I've added explanation and link. As you can see, that is design decision. If you need non-public property, use LINQ to get it `typeof(ObjectBase).GetRuntimeProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "Id")`